# Use Meteor with FileReader, get Error on read file

Tags: javascript, file-upload, meteor, filereader

I am new to Meteor. I want to access a local .csv file on the client side. I used the FileReader method, but the code always exits with Error.  Below is the code.

The html file

```
<template name="filePage">
<div>
<form id="form">
            <label>File: </label>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="filename" size="50"/><br/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload Now"/>
</form>
</div>
</template>
```

The client side .js file

```
Template.filePage.events({

    'submit form': function () { 
        var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function() {
            alert("load succeeded");
          };
        reader.onerror = function(event){    
            alert(event.target.error.code); //I got error code 4 here. 
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
    },
});
```

PS. I tried to write a html file with embedded javascript. Then the "FileReader" works fine. I guess the problem is not with my browser or my OS. 
And I tried to put the "FileReader" javascript in a Server side method, then call the method from the client. But a referenceError was thrower indicate that "the FileReader is not defined".

I could really not figure out the reason why this problem happen?? And is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You forgot to pass the `event` and `template` `(e,t)`
- You might want to stop propagation of the form submission to avoid reloading the page
  `e.stopPropagation()`
  `e.preventDefault()`
- You want to use the parsed template `t` to read the element `t.find('#file')`
- You want to use `error` to catch the error.

---

```
Template.filePage.events({
  'submit form': function (e,t) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var file = t.find('#file').files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function() {
      alert("load succeeded");
    };
    reader.onerror = function(error){    
      alert(error);
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
});
```

Comment: May I ask why we should use "e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();" here, but when I write embedded javascript (<script></script>) with html, it is not needed? Forgive me for asking naive questions, I am very new to Meteor and javascript. Thank you!

Comment: It's needed because you use `form` and `submit` which works like a link, and you dont want to leave the page. You could actually totally drop the form layer and just say `'click #submit'` insted of `'submit form'` then you wouldn't need to stop the browser from changing the page and you could delete those 2 lines. This is actually good to know because sometimes you would want to use a link `<a>` element but you dont want to it do jump pages, for example. `href='javascr...'` wouldn't be the right approach because you want to keep script and html seperate. Hope that made sense.